# R: loglikelihood of Saturated Model in GLM

Tags: r, glm, log-likelihood

Let **LL** = *loglikelihood*

**Residual Deviance** = 2(LL(*Saturated Model*) - LL(*Proposed Model)*)

However, when I use `glm` function, it seems that

```
Residual Deviance = -2LL(Proposed Model)
```

For example,

```
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)
mylogit <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
summary(mylogit)
###
Residual deviance: 458.52  on 394  degrees of freedom
AIC: 470.52
#Residual deviance
-2*logLik(mylogit)
##'log Lik.' 458.5175 (df=6)
#AIC
-2*logLik(mylogit)+2*(5+1)
##470.5175
```

Where is LL(*Saturated Model*) and how can I get it's value in R?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have got the answer: it only happens when the log likelihood of the saturated model is 0, which for discrete models implies that the probability of the observed data under the saturated model is 1.  Binary data is pretty much the *only* case where this is true (because individual fitted probabilities become either zero or one).[H](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/GLM-output-for-deviance-and-loglikelihood-td3451911.html) and [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237702/comparing-models-using-the-deviance-and-log-likelihood-ratio-tests) for details.